# How does one find the floor of the log-base-2 of an n-bit integer using bitwise operators?

Tags: algorithm, sequence, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a program in which it is necessary to calculate the floor of the log-base-2 of an integer very frequently. As a reuslt, the performance of the standard library's log2 method in my language of choice (`floor(std::log2([INT]))` from `<cmath>` in C++) is unsatisfactory, and I would like to implement the quickest version of this algorithm possible. I have found versions online which use bitwise operators to calculate this value for 32-bit and 64-bit integers:

```
INT Y(log2i)(const INT m)
{
  /* Special case, zero or negative input. */
  if (m <= 0)
    return -1;

#if SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T == 8
  /* Hash map with return values based on De Bruijn sequence. */
  static INT debruijn[64] =
  {
    0, 58, 1, 59, 47, 53, 2, 60, 39, 48, 27, 54, 33, 42, 3, 61, 51, 37, 40, 49,
    18, 28, 20, 55, 30, 34, 11, 43, 14, 22, 4, 62, 57, 46, 52, 38, 26, 32, 41,
    50, 36, 17, 19, 29, 10, 13, 21, 56, 45, 25, 31, 35, 16, 9, 12, 44, 24, 15,
    8, 23, 7, 6, 5, 63
  };

  register uint64_t v = (uint64_t)(m);

  /* Round down to one less than a power of 2. */
  v |= v >> 1;
  v |= v >> 2;
  v |= v >> 4;
  v |= v >> 8;
  v |= v >> 16;
  v |= v >> 32;

  /* 0x03f6eaf2cd271461 is a hexadecimal representation of a De Bruijn
   * sequence for binary words of length 6. The binary representation
   * starts with 000000111111. This is required to make it work with one less
   * than a power of 2 instead of an actual power of 2.
   */
  return debruijn[(uint64_t)(v * 0x03f6eaf2cd271461LU) >> 58];
#elif SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T == 4
  /* Hash map with return values based on De Bruijn sequence. */
  static INT debruijn[32] =
  {
    0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30, 8, 12, 20, 28,
    15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
  };

  register uint32_t v = (uint32_t)(m);

  /* Round down to one less than a power of 2. */
  v |= v >> 1;
  v |= v >> 2;
  v |= v >> 4;
  v |= v >> 8;
  v |= v >> 16;

  /* 0x07C4ACDD is a hexadecimal representation of a De Bruijn sequence for
   * binary words of length 5. The binary representation starts with
   * 0000011111. This is required to make it work with one less than a power of
   * 2 instead of an actual power of 2.
   */
  return debruijn[(uint32_t)(v * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
#else
#error Incompatible size of ptrdiff_t
#endif
}
```

(Above code taken from [this link](http://mad.web.cern.ch/mad/releases/madng/madng-git/lib/nfft-3.5.1/kernel/util/int.c); the comments of said code reference [this page](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn), which gives a brief overview of how the algorithm works).

I need to implement a version of this algorithm for 256-bit integers. The general form, for an n-bit integer, is fairly easy to understand: (1) create an array of integers from the Debruijn sequence with n entries; (2) perform in-place bitwise-or on the integer in question right-shifted by 2^i for i=1...(n/2); and (3) return some the entry of the Debruijn array with an index equal to the integer multiplied by a constant right-shifted by another constant.

The third step is where I'm confused. How exactly does one derive `0x07C4ACDDU` and `0x03f6eaf2cd271461LU` as the multiplication constants for 32 and 64 bits, respectively? How does one derive `58` and `27` as the constants by which one should right-shift? What would these values be for a 256-bit integer in particular?

Thanks in advance. Sorry if this is obvious, I'm not very educated in math.

Comment: I'm sure this can be solved in the way you're suggesting, but are you open to other solutions? For example, chopping the 256bit integer into pieces of 64, finding the highest nonzero chunk, and then using [std::countl_zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero).

Comment: @harold std::countl_zero isn't really ideal, since it doesn't seem to work with the type in question (`boost::multiprecision::uint256_t`), and there's no overload/alternative that I can find in the `boost::multiprecision` library. Do you know of alternatives which would work in these cirumstances?

Comment: Certainly it's not as convenient as merely calling that function, but I didn't suggest that, I meant that you would search for the most-significant chunk of the number that isn't zero, and then quickly locate the most-significant set bit within that single chunk by calling `countl_zero` on that chunk (not on the whole 256bit thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with harold that `std::countl_zero()` is the way to go. Memory
has gotten a lot slower relative to compute since this bit-twiddling
hack was designed, and processors typically have built-in instructions.

To answer your question, however, this hack combines a couple
primitives. (When I talk about bit indexes, I'm counting from most to
least significant, starting the count at zero.)

1. The sequence of lines starting with `v |= v >> 1;` achieves its
   stated goal of rounding up to the nearest power of two minus one
   (i.e., a number whose binary representation matches `0*1*`) by
   setting every bit to the right of at least one set bit.

   - None of these lines clears bits in `v`.
   - Since there are right shifts only, every bit set by these lines
     is to the right of at least one set bit.
   - Given a set bit at position `i`, we observe that a bit at
     position `i + delta` will be guaranteed set by the lines
     matching `delta`'s binary representation, e.g., `delta = 13`
     (1101 in binary) is handled by
     `v |= v >> 1; v |= v >> 4; v |= v >> 8;`.
2. Extracting bits `[L, L+delta)` from an unsigned integer `n` with
   `WIDTH` bits can be accomplished with `(n << L) >> (WIDTH - delta)`.
   The left shift truncates the upper bits that should be discarded,
   and the right shift, which is logical in C++ for unsigned, truncates
   the lower bits and fills the truncated upper bits with zeros.
3. Given that the answer is `k`, we want to extract 5 (= log2(32), for
   32-bit) or 6 (= log2(64), for 64-bit) bits starting with index `k`
   from the magic constant `n`. We can't shift by `k` because we only
   know `pow2(k)` (sort of, I'll get to that in a second), but we can
   use the equivalence between multiplying by `pow2(k)` and left
   shifting by `k` as a workaround.
4. Actually we only know `pow2(k+1) - 1`. We're going to be greedy and
   shave the two ops that we'd need to get `pow2(k)`. By putting 5 or 6
   ones after the initial zeros, we force that minus one to always
   cause the answer to be one less than it should have been (mod 32 or
   64).
5. So the de Bruijn sequence: the idea is that we can uniquely identify
   our index in the sequence by reading the next 5 or 6 bits. We aren't
   so lucky as to be able to have these bits be equal to the index,
   which is where the look-up table comes in.

As an example, I'll adapt this algorithm to 8-bit words. We start with

```cpp
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
```

The de Bruijn sequence is `00011101`, which written out in three-bit
segments is

| (index − 1) mod 8 | bits | value | (value − 1) mod 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 000 | 0 | 7 |
| 0 | 001 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 011 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 111 | 7 | 6 |
| 3 | 110 | 6 | 5 |
| 4 | 101 | 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 010 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 100 | 4 | 3 |

The hex constant is `0x1D`, the right shift is 8 − log2(8) = 5, the
table is derived by inverting the permutation above:
`{0, 5, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 7}`.

So, hypothetically, if we wanted to adapt this algorithm to a 256-bit
word size, we'd add `v |= v >> 64; v |= v >> 128;`, change the shift to
256 − log2(256) = 256 − 8 = 248, find a 256-bit de Bruijn sequence that
starts with `0000000011111111`, encode it as a hex constant, and
construct the appropriate look-up table to pair with it.

But like, don't. If you insist on not using the library function, you're
still probably on a 64-bit machine, so you should just test whether each
of the four words from big to little is nonzero, and if so, apply the
64-bit code and add the appropriate offset.

Comment: For practical purposes, you're probably right about `countl_zero`. However, I was wondering if you could elaborate on how you "find a 256-bit de Bruijn sequence that starts with 0000000011111111". Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesBuchanan Wikipedia describes some construction algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction